# How do SSL authenticated users prove authenticity through UDP packets?

Tags: ssl, udp, ssl-certificate

I chose SSL for registration in my game client. The client communicates with the game server which stores a salted/hashed password.

If I use SSL to authenticate users on login, but the game does all of it's communication with UDP packets, how does the server know that the UDP packets it's receiving is from the authenticated user?

Comment: Note that I'm mostly interested in ensuring the user is authenticated. I don't care about the privacy of the UDP packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potentially you can provide a token via SSL, and pass that token in your UDP packets. But this is useless without encryption: an attacker can intercept the UDP packet, grab the token and quickly do the attack using stolen token.

Another option would be to exchange symmetric keys via SSL and use those keys to encrypt UDP packets. But to do this properly you would have to also add MAC, an finally you will end up reinventing TLS :).

The best option is to employ DTLS - the flavor of TLS that works over UDP. All your communication will be authenticated and protected this way. Possibility to use DTLS depends on what language/platform you use and what external libraries (if any) you can invoke.